# Tensorboard - 'sending 404' error

Tags: tensorflow

Couldn't launch tensorboard on Windows PC. Could someone please resolve this issues.

`C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35>tensorboard --logdir = ".\graphs" --port 6006
Starting TensorBoard b'47' at http://0.0.0.0:6006
(Press CTRL+C to quit)
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404
WARNING:tensorflow:path ../external\data/plugin/text/runs not found, sending 404`

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can try this way. First locate to the log path (e.g your log file location to D:\tensorflow\log2\events.out.tfevents.1496458732.CZ-20170420JASY), you
cd to D:\tensorflow\log2 , then run the cmd command
`tensorboard --logdir=log2`.
I have tried this way, and see the graph.